# Show full names in GHC's heap profiler file

Tags: haskell, command, command-line-interface, ghc, heap-profiling

I was trying to understand GHC's heap profiling file. But names are shortened.

```
JOB "tutd -d db +RTS -h -s -p"
DATE "Thu Oct 21 09:02 2021"
SAMPLE_UNIT "seconds"
VALUE_UNIT "bytes"
BEGIN_SAMPLE 0.000000
END_SAMPLE 0.000000
BEGIN_SAMPLE 0.095057
(3622)decodeCurrent/Project...  96
(2781)parseArgs/opts/crRead...  48
(3824)calculateMerkleHash.d...  24
(2583)main      16
(2848)readGraphTransactionI...  48
(2843)openLockFile/setupDat...  16
(2782)parsePersistenceStrat...  16
(3606)validateMerkleHashes/...  32
```

Is there any way to expand it? I couldn't find it in [UserGuide/Profiling](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/9.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/profiling.html).

Answer (score 0):

The full name of a cost centre is in dot prof file.
I can get more infos by querying no.

```
[nix-shell:~/...]# cat tutd.prof | grep 'COST CENTRE *MODULE\|2781\|2583\|2848'
COST CENTRE                 MODULE                               SRC                                                       %time %alloc
COST CENTRE                                                   MODULE                                          SRC                                                                 no.      entries  %time %alloc   %time %alloc
 main                                                         Main                                            tutd.hs:(85,1)-(109,70)                                             2583           0    0.0    0.0    99.9   99.9
     readGraphTransactionIdFileDigest                         ProjectM36.TransactionGraph.Persist             ProjectM36/TransactionGraph/Persist.hs:(205,1)-(207,53)             2848           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
                   parseArgs                                  Main                                            tutd.hs:(24,1)-(25,172)                                             2781           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
```